# RestTemplate POST Request with Request Parameters

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am using Spring's `RestTemplate` to send a POST request to my RestController with request parameters and a request header.

It fails with this error message: `POST request for "[myurl]" resulted in 404 (null); invoking error handler`.

Note that `"[myurl]"` is `"http://localhost:8080/test"`

This is my code:

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
MultiValueMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Integer>();
map.add("num1", 1);//request parameters
map.add("num2", 2);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();//request header
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Integer>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Integer>>(map, headers);
Object obj = rest.postForObject("[myurl]", request, Object.class);
logger.log("Returned object: " + obj.toString());
```

Comment: what is this `"[myurl]"` @user

Comment: @Deadpool It's just the URL for my RestController method.

Comment: can you post the url? why are you using square brackets ?

Comment: @Deadpool I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: but i believe you url input is not valid, it says request for url not found

Comment: @Deadpool The URL is `http://localhost:8080/test`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176756/discussion-between-deadpool-and-sdlfyeiwyrw).

Comment: In the code, the comment says that the map is your request parameters, but you appear to be sending it as the request body. Request parameters would be reflected in the URL like: `?num1=1&num2=2`.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas How should I send POST request parameters? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing something like (if you can get away with MultiValueMap):

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("num1", 1);//request parameters
map.put("num2", 2);

Object obj = rest.postForObject("[myurl]", map, Object.class);
logger.log("Returned object: " + obj.toString());
```